# python script to change names of BAM files according to their PATHS

Tags: python-3.x

I have different bam files from multiple folders : folder structure is:

```
Folder1/sample1/libx/folder1/alginment.bam    
Folder1/sample2/liby/folder1/alginment.bam     
Folder1/sample3/libsome/foldersome/alginment.bam
```

I want to change the names  of these bam files to :

```
Folder1/sample1.libx.folder1.alginment.bam      
Folder1/sample2.liby.folder1.alginment.bam             
Folder1/sample3.libsome.foldersome.alginment.bam
```

How can I replace names these BAM files in python?

Thanks